# How to align certain text in emacs vhdl-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, vhdl, emacs24

In Emacs how would I align a group of text:

```
signal slv4   : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal slv16  : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal slv8   : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal slv32  : std_logic_vector(32 downto 0);
```

so it looks like this

```
signal slv4   : std_logic_vector( 3 downto 0);
signal slv16  : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal slv8   : std_logic_vector( 7 downto 0);
signal slv32  : std_logic_vector(32 downto 0);
```

Basically I want to right justify the numbers before "downto"; another side effect is that the text is right justified (the semi-colons line up).

How would I achieve this?  I have played around with `M-x align` and `M-x align-regexp` however I can't seem to get what I'm looking for.

Also I'm using vhdl-mode so maybe it has something built in?

Comment: Check out this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895930/right-align-text-in-emacs

Comment: Have you tried the VHDL mode beautify? It's under the VHDL->beautify menu.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks I ended up implementing my own function as follows: `(defun my-align-downto (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (align-regexp beg end "\\([0-9]* downto*\\)" -1 0 t))`

Comment: So all I do is highlight the desired code and call my function by `M-x my-align-downto`  Which seems to work out OK.  @ pknodle This feature is not implemented in vhdl-mode afk, does it work on yours?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such a thing in vhdl mode because you need spaces in the middle of the text. If it were just about right aligning, you could possibly play around with `tab` behaviour. In this case, you could use a macro.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros

Answer (score 0):

In a first run the maximum of padding is detected, than called recursively with padding given.

Edit `this-regexp' inside let if something different is needed.
Maybe the hard-coded opening "(" in concat-form needs edit than too.

```
(defun my-numbers-padded (&optional beg end len)
  "Pad numbers as given in example string "
  (interactive "*")
  (let* ((beg (cond (beg)
                    ((use-region-p)
                     (region-beginning))
                    (t (point-min))))
         (end (cond (end (copy-marker end))
                    ((use-region-p)
                     (copy-marker (region-end)))
                    (t (copy-marker (point-max)))))
         (this-regexp "^\\([^(]+\\)\(\\([0-9]+\\)\\(.+\\)$")
         (len len)
         lenmax
         (var (and len (concat "(format \"%" (number-to-string len) "s\" (match-string-no-properties 2))"))))
    (goto-char beg)
    (if len
        (while (re-search-forward this-regexp  nil t 1)
          (setq erg (eval (car (read-from-string var))))
          (replace-match
           (concat (match-string-no-properties 1) "\("   erg (match-string-no-properties 3))))
      (while (re-search-forward this-regexp  nil t 1)
        (setq current-length (length (match-string-no-properties 2)))
        (if (and lenmax (< lenmax current-length))
            (setq lenmax current-length)
          (unless lenmax (setq lenmax current-length))))
      (my-padding-numbers beg end lenmax))))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't get this to work, I may need to study my Lisp a bit to figure out how this works.  If this function works on the entire buffer then that would save me the trouble of selecting regions and rigging up a `align-regexp` as I did above.

Comment: @mrbean beg and end are set conditionally. If no region exists and beg/end not given as arguments, it works at the whole buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I'm currently using (which works fine):

```
(defun my-align-downto (beg end)
    (interactive "r")
    (align-regexp beg end "\\([0-9]* downto*\\)" -1 0 t))
```

I thought I would take it one step further and create my own 'align hook' based on the information at the very bottom of this page: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AlignCommands#toc8

```
(add-hook 'align-load-hook (lambda ()
    (add-to-list 'align-rules-list
      '(downto-align
        (regexp  . "\\([0-9]* downto*\\)")
        (group   . -1)
        (spacing . 0)
        (modes   . vhdl-mode)
        (repeat  . t)))))
```

With which I get no results. :(

Does vhdl-mode override these alignment rules.. or am I just not doing something correctly?

Comment: Does `(modes . '(vhdl-mode))` fix it?

Comment: I think it did but now I get an error...  "Args out of range: -1, 0".  It doesn't seem to like my 'Group' setting?

Comment: Ah, you've gotten confused by how `align-regexp` triggers justification. You want `(group . 1) (justify . t)`. Check the `align-rules-list` documentation.